# Can not work internationalization in spring mvc with thymeleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, internationalization, thymeleaf, resourcemanager

I have started a project with Spring MVC with thymeleaf. I want to that it is internationalize. I had copied official spring tutorial. But When I click tr button , words aren't changed. I am pasting my codes. I assumed that getLabel function of ResourceManager service is getting label current language. But I am not sure. How can I proceed?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.yummynoodlebar.web.controller","com.yummynoodlebar.web.service","com.yummynoodlebar.web.domain"})
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
    registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor);
}

@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {

    CookieLocaleResolver cookieLocaleResolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
    cookieLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(StringUtils.parseLocaleString("en"));
    return cookieLocaleResolver;
}

@Bean
public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
resolver.setSuffix(".html");
//NB, selecting HTML5 as the template mode.
resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
resolver.setCacheable(false);
return resolver;

}

@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
return engine; 
}

@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {

ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
viewResolver.setOrder(1);
viewResolver.setViewNames(new String[]{"*"});
viewResolver.setCache(false);
    return viewResolver;
}

@Bean(name = "labelSource")
public MessageSource messageSource() {

    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:i18n/labels");
    // if true, the key of the message will be displayed if the key is not
    // found, instead of throwing a NoSuchMessageException
    messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    // # -1 : never reload, 0 always reload
    messageSource.setCacheSeconds(0);
    return messageSource;
}

}

@Component
public class ResourceManager {

@Resource(name = "labelSource")
private MessageSource messageSource;

public String getLabel(String code) {
    return messageSource.getMessage(code, null, Locale.getDefault());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem. I had changed getLabel function. New code is following

```
public String getLabel(String code) {
    return messageSource.getMessage(code, null, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
}
```